# Extract all json value in comm saparated string in oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have following Array **:**

```
 "Sorted Reason Code Table": [
                  "PCC018",
                  "PCC020",
                  "PCC021",
                  "PCC023",
                  "PCC025",
                  "PCC031",
                  "PCC059",
                  "PCC061",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ]
```

I want to get all values in string. Output should be **:**

`PCC010,PCC012,PCC0034 etc.`

All values are dynamic some time there will be value and some time it would be blank .

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(reason_code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS reason_codes
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$."Sorted Reason Code Table"[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           reason_code VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$'
         )
       ) j
WHERE  reason_code IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t.ROWID
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value BLOB CHECK (value IS JSON));

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
VALUES ('{"Sorted Reason Code Table": ["PCC018","PCC020","PCC021","PCC023","PCC025","PCC031","PCC059","PCC061","","","","","","","","","","",""]}');
```

Outputs:

> | REASON_CODES |
> | --- |
> | PCC018,PCC020,PCC021,PCC023,PCC025,PCC031,PCC059,PCC061 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=20dd046f8ab7e88f408fa089a31bfe05)*

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.1e7294ffbec0463785df4e3599bfc967  
this is my JSON file can you please help me to get those code from this JSON. I'm new to JSON stuff .  Thanks in advance

Comment: This is taking lots of time. Can you help me to reduce execution time plz.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (abusing the `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function by telling it that the reason codes are in format JSON, when in fact they aren't). Using the data from MT0's answer.

```
select substr(lst, 2, length(lst) - 2) as reason_codes
from   (
         select json_arrayagg(reason_code format json
                              order by reason_code) as lst
         from   table_name t cross apply
                json_table(t.value, '$."Sorted Reason Code Table"[*]'
                           columns (reason_code varchar2(10) path '$')
                          )
       )
;




REASON_CODES                                              
----------------------------------------------------------
PCC018,PCC020,PCC021,PCC023,PCC025,PCC031,PCC059,PCC061
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. jsoneditoronline.org/… this is my JSON file can you please help me to get those code from this JSON. I'm new to JSON stuff . Thanks in advance